# Video onended() or ended does not fire in Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, html5-video

The following code works perfectly in Chrome or in Firefox on Desktop but doesn't work in Safari on iOS.

```
<video class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin" preload playsinline webkit-playsinline  data-setup='{ "inactivityTimeout": 0 }' disablePictureInPicture controls muted controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen noremoteplayback" id="fVideo">
     <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

...and here is the javascript

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('fVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        alert('video ended');
    }
</script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced Javascript code with the videojs function callback, and it works now.

```
<script>
    var player = videojs('fVideo');
    var options = {};
    var player = videojs('fVideo', options, function onPlayerReady() {
        this.on('ended', function() {
            alert('video ended');
        });
    });
</script>
```